# Pig script/command to filter files on specific strings

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, apache-pig, tweets

I am trying to write Hadoop Pig script which will take 2 files and filter based on string i.e

**words.txt**

```
google 
facebook 
twitter 
linkedin
```

**tweets.json**

```
{"created_time": "18:47:31 ", "text": "RT @Joey7Barton: ..give a facebook about whether the americans wins a Ryder cup. I mean surely he has slightly more important matters. #fami ...", "user_id": 450990391, "id": 252479809098223616, "created_date": "Sun Sep 30 2012"}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
twitter  = LOAD 'Twitter.json' USING JsonLoader('created_time:chararray, text:chararray, user_id:chararray, id:chararray, created_date:chararray');
    filtered = FILTER twitter BY (text MATCHES '.*facebook.*');
    extracted = FOREACH filtered GENERATE 'facebook' AS pattern,id, user_id, created_time, created_date, text;
    final = GROUP extracted BY pattern;
    dump final;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(facebook,{(facebook,252545104890449921,291041644,23:06:59 ,Sun Sep 30 2012,RT @Joey7Barton: ..give a facebook about whether the americans wins a Ryder cup. I mean surely he has slightly more important matters. #fami ...)})
```

the output that im getting is, **without loading the words.txt file** i.e by filtering the tweet directly.

I need to get the output as

```
(facebook)(complete tweet of that facebook word contained)
```

i.e it should read the words.txt and as words are reading according to that it should get all the tweets from tweets.json file

Any help

Mohan.V

Comment: May be I am missing something, but where have you used the words.txt file exactly in the script?

Comment: No i didnt used in mentioned script.But i want to.

Comment: How can i use words.txt and get the output as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You could think something in direction of running multiple statements within FOREACH statement. Something like this-

```
final = FOREACH words  {
            a = CONCAT(CONCAT('.*',words.$0),'.*') as aaa;
            filtered = FILTER twitter BY (text MATCHES aaa);
        generate a, flatten(filtered) as output; }
```

Please note that this is just to give an idea and I have not tested it. I will try test as soon as I get access to the Pig environment, but this should get you started.

Comment: Got error....mismatched input 'as' expecting SEMI_COLON.....I know it is a small thing.But I am very new to PIG.So pls suggest me.